# Is there a constant L such that the function below is continuous at 0?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Is there a constant L such that the function below is continuous at 0?
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
 x \big/ \sqrt{1-\cos 2x} & : \mbox{if }x \in (-\pi; 0) \cup (0; \pi) 
\\[1ex]  L & : \mbox{if }x = 0
\end{cases}$$

I'm sorry about the formatting, I'm new to this site. It's supposed to be a system of equations. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

[edit: Formatting corrected for you. Welcome to the site.]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to show that as $x$ approaches $0$ from above and below, the function approaches the same value, and identify this value.

You also need to show that there are no discontinuities elsewhere in that interval.

Now, can you evaluate the left and right limits at zero?

Comment: I found that both limits were 0, but the graph shows something different. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Carolyn Yes.  The limits are not zero.